# How to loop through appended inputs inside an array

Tags: php, arrays, json, loops, append

I'm submitting appended inputs through an API. The number of items is different every time. When I submit the form, the input is submitted successfully and an object is returned, but only the last appended input is submitted. How can I run a loop inside of the array shown, or what syntax of loop works here so that I will submit a new item for each appended input? thank you for considering.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#new").click(function(){
        $("table").append("<tr><td><input type= 'text' name = 'item[]'</td> </tr>");
    });
});
</script>

<?php
```

after a form/table with input name="item[]" my PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
   $size = sizeof($_POST['item']);
   for ($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++)  
   {
      $product = $_POST['item'][$i];
   }
   $fields = array(
      'customer' => 992058,
      'items' => [
                    [
                        'name' => $product,
                    ]
                 ]
   );

// HERE IS A CURL CALL that POSTS $fields AND RETURNS JSON
?>
```

the JSON I'd like to see returned might look something like

```
"items":[{"name":"product1"}][{"name":"product2"}];
```

instead of what I'm getting which is

```
"items":[{"name":"product2"}]
```

Comment: is there any particular reason why you start you loop at position = 1 ? Can you dump your `$_POST['item']` array? or show how items are located there and what index do they have.

Comment: you are right about position = 1. I fixed that to zero. var_dump returns a string, and if I place it within the loop, it returns all inputs. but only the last input creates a new item with a name. does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you need to:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {

        $size = sizeof($_POST['item']);
        $products = [];

        for ($i = 1; $i < $size; $i++)  

            {

                $products[]['name'] = $_POST['item'][$i];
            }

            $fields = array(

                        'customer' => 992058,


                        'items' => $products
                            );
```

The problem with your code that var `$product` get only the last insert while running through the loop, you need to create an array inside the loop.

Comment: thank you Serghei, I've gotten far enough along that your answer was most useful